# Setup that selects automation server (written in .NET) in excel

Tags: excel, excel-interop

We have some excel formulas written in .NET and exposed to Excel via COM. The user who wants use our formulas have to:

1. run some bat file that registers dll's into COM (using RegAsm)
2. then in Excel (2010) select File|Options|Add-ins|Excel Add-ins|Automation|Select our server|GO|GO

We want to avoid the (2.) using some automatic setup. Does anybody have any idea how it can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have not had an answer in some time. I do not know that this will work, but it may be worth trying:

```
Sub Add_an_Addin()

Dim oAddin As AddIn
Dim oTempBk As Workbook


Set oTempBk = Workbooks.Add

Set oAddin = AddIns.Add("E:\CostBenefit1.0.xla", True)
oAddin.Installed = True

oTempBk.Close

End Sub
```

FROM: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/06/excel-vba-install-excel-add-in-xla-or.html